# R timestamp conversion

Tags: r, date

I have a timestamp that gives me the time that has elapsed since the beginning of a data recording. I need to transform this timestamp into a time format now, but I am experiencing difficulties here.

```
timestamp <- 69436  ## milliseconds elapsed since beginning of recording
```

I have played around with as.POSIXct with `format="%H:%M:%OS"` also setting the options for the number of digits, but cannot get the correct result, which should be

```
time_elapsed <- "00:01:09.436000"  ## Just so you know what the result should be, I know that as.POSIXct() will also give a date
```

Can I do `as.POSIXct()` on a timestamp that includes milliseconds or what should the input be?

Or am I completely on the wrong track here?

Any help and ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: You want a duration and not a time.

Comment: Sure, but if I start from 00:00:00.0000 hours, duration and time should be the same.

Comment: I would have recommended chron, but it only displays full seconds: `library(chron); times(timestamp/1000/3600/24)`. But you can use the `as.POSIXct` method for class numeric and use `format.POSIXct` if you only have durations smaller than a day.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you're getting at, but you can set the amount of digits using %OSn where n is the number of digits:

```
format( as.POSIXct(Sys.Date())+timestamp/1000, "%M:%S:%OS6")
```

will yield

```
[1] "01:09:09.436000"
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that before too. However, I lose the information about the hours then. I found a probably somewhat "dirty" workaround, but it does its job. Thanks for your ideas!